# Expect/Send Issue

Tags: linux, bash, expect

Currently, I am working on a script to automatize a process, in this point my script is short and simple but I have had some Issues with `expect/send`.

code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
#!/bin/bash

set ip ***
set ip2 ***
set user ***
set usr2 ***
set OTP [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh "usr@$ip";
expect "OTP Password:"
send -- "$OTP"
interact
expect "prompt >"
send -- "ssh usr2@$ip2"
interact
```

For this point script works until the **first** ssh but... for the **second** ssh (`expect "prompt >" / send -- "ssh $ip2"`) It doesn't work... I don't get the idea why. I have tried with some commands like expect `eof`, `wait`, `timeout` and nothing as well I checked to expect version is on latest (5.45).

Do you have any idea? thanks!

Comment: Add this 1interact
EOD
echo "you're out"`

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your `spawn` looks fine to me, but in the `send`, you forgot to send the carriage return, which actually terminates the command:

```
send -- "$OTP\r"
```